# Facebook Page Ads pay scheme

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

Does anyone here have any experience with Facebook Page Ads and can explain me, how Facebook payment scheme works in this case?

I've setup a test, three days long, Facebook Page Ad, using PayPal and one of my credit cards, that is attached to that PayPal's account. Ad is working just fine, Facebook claims, that it displayed it more than a thousand times and I have received noticable increase in likes of my ad-adverted page.

However, I see **not even a trace** of that payment anywhere, neither in PayPal's (one-time payments or recurring payments) nor in bank (credit-card pre-charges list or charges already on account).

When should I see this payment in both PayPal and bank account history? I've set three-days long  ad campaign with lowest budget ($5 / day) and it is running now for 2,5 days, ending within next 6 hours. Will Facebook charge my PayPal account / credit card not eariler then ad campaign is over?

I setup 3 days x $5 and provided PayPal (or credit card) details *before* my ad campaign started, so I was pretty sure, that Facebook will charge me immediately, to *secure* its payments.

Now, when it looks like it charges upon campaign end (or correct me, what am I missing?), isn't that a security leak of some kind? I mean -- I can provide a fully working credit card and made it not payable within these three days (pass its limits). Or I can provide working PayPal account before ad campaign starts and then remove all bank accounts and all credit cards from it, so it will not be able to pay to Facebook upon ad campaign end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't reached the first threshold of $25 USD https://www.facebook.com/help/105373712886516. In addition Facebook may charge every few days. The charge will stay on your account until paid I believe if you remove banking information.

Comment: There is nothing about $25 USD threshold in linked Facebook answer, but I get your point -- until I reach $25 I may not be billed. And once I pass that, I can be billed once per day in most cases. Am I right?